# How can I slideUp a div when a other div slidesDown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want if I click on a DIV that a other DIV shows up, but the other div needs to close. I tried some `if` statements but I never worked with that before

```js
$(".hiddenweb").on("click", function() {
  $(".websitehulp").slideDown("900"), 100;
  $(".emailhulp").slideUp("900"), 100;
  $(".hostinghelp").slideUp("900"), 100;
  $(".onderhoudhelp").slideUp("900"), 100;
});

$(".emaillekker").on("click", function() {
  $(".emailhulp").slideDown("900"), 100;
  $(".websitehulp").slideUp("900"), 100;
  $(".hostinghelp").slideUp("900"), 100;
  $(".onderhoudhelp").slideUp("900"), 100;
});

$(".hostinglekker").on("click", function() {
  $(".hostinghelp").slideDown("900"), 100;
  $(".websitehulp").slideUp("900"), 100;
  $(".emailhulp").slideUp("900"), 100;
  $(".onderhoudhelp").slideUp("900"), 100;
});

$(".onderhoudlekker").on("click", function() {
  $(".onderhoudhelp").slideDown("900"), 100;
  $(".hostinghelp").slideUp("900"), 100;
  $(".emailhulp").slideUp("900"), 100;
  $(".websitehulp").slideUp("900"), 100;
});
```

I expected that the delay was enough that the div would wait it to close before the other div opens up

Comment: Your code should be working fine. Can you please add the relevant HTML to the question so we can test it

Answer (score 0):

May b I am wrong. but i think you want to slide up and down between two divs.

```
$(".slide1").click(function(){    
    if($(".slideDiv1").hasClass("noDisplay")){
       $(".slideDiv1").removeClass("noDisplay").show("slide");
       $(".slideDiv2").addClass("noDisplay").hide("slide");       
     }    
  });

$(".slide2").click(function(){    
    if($(".slideDiv2").hasClass("noDisplay")){
       $(".slideDiv2").removeClass("noDisplay").show("slide") ;
       $(".slideDiv1").addClass("noDisplay").hide("slide");       
    }

  });
```

Here is working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/to5p9cnu/1/)

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are looking for an `acccordion`-like component:

```js
function AccordionCtrl() {
  const item = jQuery(this);
  const isOpen = item.hasClass('is-open');

  if (isOpen) {
    item.removeClass('is-open');
    return;
  }
  
  item.siblings().each(
    (i, sibling) => jQuery(sibling).removeClass('is-open'),
  );

  return item.addClass('is-open');
}

jQuery('.accordion').on('click', '.accordion-item', AccordionCtrl);
```

```css
.accordion {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.accordion-item {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  min-height: 30px;
  background: cyan;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: 250ms min-height linear;
}

.accordion-item.is-open {
  min-height: 150px;
}

.accordion-item:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-item is-open"></div>
  <div class="accordion-item"></div>
  <div class="accordion-item"></div>
  <div class="accordion-item"></div>
</div>
```